# Cant create queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

For a test I created a free tier IoT Hub and basic service bus. But when I click on the "+ Queue" and fill out all the fields; setting name, size (1gb), message to to live (14 days, default), lock duration (30 seconds, default) and only "Enable partitioning" I get this errormessage when I click create:

The property 'AutoDeleteOnIdle' cannot be set when creating a Queue because the namespace 'x' is using 'Basic' tier.

I should be able to create queues, but not topics with this setup. Are one of the properties of the "Create queue" blade running with a different naming convention from "AutoDeleteOnIdle"?

Comment: I went with the defaults for a queue on basic tier and it worked.

Comment: I had the same problem creating a service bus queue in the portal under the basic tier. I opened a support case with Microsoft and they say it is a known issue that they are working on.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, guess I have to go standard tier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The property 'AutoDeleteOnIdle' cannot be set when creating a Queue because the namespace 'x' is using 'Basic' tier.

I could reproduce the issue with the following sample when I am using 'Basic' tier.

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

namespaceManager.CreateQueue(new QueueDescription("testqueue") {
    DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    EnablePartitioning = true,
    AutoDeleteOnIdle = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) });
}
```

***Exception***

[image]

After I scale it to standard tier, the above code works fine. If possible, please try to scale to standard tier and check if you could create queue&specify the property AutoDeleteOnIdle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've initially created a service bus with basic. Later I realized that topic is not supported in basic. So, I've deleted the service bus component and recreated a new service bus component with Standard using the same name that I've used before. But, I got above error "SubCode=40000. The property 'AutoDeleteOnIdle' cannot be set when creating a Queue because the namespace 'dev-sb-xxx' is using 'Basic' tier.."

It seems to be a bug to me with azure portal. When I checked scale, it is still shown as basic. I've changed it to Standard and it worked fine.

Comment: what to you mean by "I checked scale"?